# Run list of calls and end them

Tags: java, android, arraylist, telephonymanager

I got list of numbers and I have to make call foreach number and end it after 10 sec and start the new call.
code is working to make calls but after finish with all list item calling is not stopping its continuesly making calls with first number only?

```
private void StartCalling()
    {
        try
        {
            if(allNumbers.size() != 0)
            {
                countDown = allNumbers.size();
                for (Iterator<String> iter = allNumbers.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
                        final String num = iter.next();
                        final TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                        PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + num));
                                    startActivity(callIntent);
                                }
                            }
                        };
                        tManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
                }
            }else
            {
                Message.message(CTX,"Not a calling number..");
            }
        }catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Message.message(CTX,"" + ex);
        }

    }
```

and to end the call after 10 seconds.

```
public class PhoneCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
    CountDownTimer mCountDownTimer;
    long countdownPeriod;
    long remainingCount;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {
            TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            PhoneStateListener phoneStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                    if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                            countdownPeriod = 10000;
                            createCountDownTimer(context);
                    }
                }
            };
            tManager.listen(phoneStateListener,PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void createCountDownTimer(final Context context) {
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(countdownPeriod, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long l = millisUntilFinished/1000;
                countdownPeriod = l;
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                Class c = null;
                try {
                    c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
                    if(c != null)
                    {
                        Method m = tm.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
                        m.setAccessible(true);
                        Object iTelephony = m.invoke(tm);
                        Method m2 = iTelephony.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("endCall");
                        m2.invoke(iTelephony);
                    }
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you define and add values to `allNumbers`?

Comment: its a List<string> and in spinner item selected I'm getting the values from DB and adding to this list. List<String> AllNumbers define as global to class.

Comment: did you try to loop thru the numbers without an `iterator`? something like `for (String number : allNumbers) {...`?

Comment: Yes that is what I was using it before but later on i decided delete the items from list using iter.remove() as finishing up with call but that is also didn't help, in fact creates more problems so I removed this iter.remove().